# Microsoft Access Count if

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an access table with several columns that is populated from ms access form.

I need to count the total of each column where the value is Y or N and not NA

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
Count(tableName.[ColumnName] ='y' ) AS MyTotal
FROM tableName;
```

The query is returning the total number of rows not just the ones with a Y in them.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong

thanks in advance

Comment: @scragar Access doesn't support the CASE statement. Your solution is incorrect.

Answer (score 6):

You're putting your `WHERE` clause criteria in the wrong spot. Really, you want a `COUNT` of your column, `WHERE` the column equals some value.

Try this:

```
SELECT Count(YourColumn) AS MyTotal
FROM YourTable
WHERE YourColumn='y'
```

I suppose if you were looking for another solution, this should work as well.

```
SELECT SUM(IIf(YourColumn = 'y', 1, 0)) AS MyTotal
FROM YourTable
```

What the `IIf` does is it gives a value of 1 to each record where your column equals 'y', and a 0 to the columns that don't fit that criteria. Then to replicate the `COUNT` functionality, we simply `SUM` them up.